# ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks-iphonesimulator'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, preview

I have problem running `Xcode previews` in my project. Once I try to start it I get the following error no matter the view I'm trying to preview. Running the app on physical device or simulator works just fine.

```
linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

----------------------------------------

LinkDylibError: Failed to build CustomTextField.swift

Linking failed: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks-iphonesimulator'
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "___llvm_profile_runtime", referenced from:
      ___llvm_profile_runtime_user in FBLPromises(PromisesObjC-dummy.o)
      ___llvm_profile_runtime_user in FBLPromises(FBLPromise.o)
      ___llvm_profile_runtime_user in FBLPromises(FBLPromise+All.o)
      ___llvm_profile_runtime_user in FBLPromises(FBLPromise+Always.o)
      ___llvm_profile_runtime_user in FBLPromises(FBLPromise+Any.o)
      ___llvm_profile_runtime_user in FBLPromises(FBLPromise+Async.o)
      ___llvm_profile_runtime_user in FBLPromises(FBLPromise+Catch.o)
      ...
     (maybe you meant: ___llvm_profile_runtime_user)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have already tried reintegrating pods and removing `Framework Search Paths` as `-F` option suggested it in above error. This brought no success.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had a similar issue and solved it by adding -fprofile-instr-generate to Build Settings > Linking > Other Linker Flags

Comment: Thank you very much. Tried all of the solutions from stack and other sources and nothing worked for me. Your's did the magic trick and now my previews are fully operational :)

Comment: you're the champ @Andy

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it. Can you please explain what this flag does?

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was some cache conflict.

The same error, with undefined symbols of some struct name from swift package loaded into Xcode project:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option
'-F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks-iphonesimulator'
Undefined symbols for architecture
```

It turned out to be two different swift packages with the same name. They've even been connected to different projects.

Spent couple of hours figuring. Renamed one of the packages, and error was gone.